# Pinterest Pin It Button on Blogger

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I'm trying to append &media= in between the +data:post.url and the +data:blog.postImageUrl blogger data tags in a link so it can work with Pinterest.

The link works when I use the +data:post.url on it's own:

```
<a data-pin-color='red' data-pin-config='beside' expr:href='&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&quot;+data:post.url'><img src='//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_red_20.png'/></a>
```

when I try to add the image reference it doesn't work:

```
<a data-pin-color='red' data-pin-config='beside' expr:href='&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&quot;+data:post.url+&quot;&amp;media=&quot;+data:blog.postImageUrl'>
```

This is the original Pinterest code (found [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/)):

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
    ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F
    &media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg
    &description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest"
    data-pin-do="buttonPin"
    data-pin-config="above">
    <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>
```

Any ideas or insights?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `data:postFirstImageUrl` data tag (only in posts).